# Excel VBA, how can I count up all my visable fields?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this excel file, which is an export of a sharepoint list. In this list I have a field that I filter on:

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, _
    Criteria1:="Daily"
```

I look at each field to see if it contains the word red or green, if it does, then add it to the count so that later I can take an average.
Now, the issue that I am having, all this above works great, but it looks at all the fields, not just the ones that are showing via the filter.

Does anyone know how I can get VBA to look only at the filtered items?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the method you want to use is Range.SpecialCells. It is referenced at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx.

The type constant you want to use is xlCellTypeVisible so it would be something like:
    Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)